# How to shorten my python code for selenium please

Tags: python, selenium, time

I start on python and I am not all the basics
here is my script which retrieves some text and which goes to the next page when it does, I would like to make it more readable for everyone.
I would like to do for loops and condition
I don't know how I can use the class in this case, I have small (<driver.execute_script ("window.scrollTo (0, 2520);")>)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
url = driver.get("https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/abecedaire/a/1/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 220);")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1320);")
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2720);")
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4220);")
time.sleep(2.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_A = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul')
Mot_Commencent_Par_A = Mot_Commencent_Par_A.text.split('\n')
time.sleep(2.5)
Page_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')
page_2 = Page_2.click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1020);")
time.sleep(2)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AA = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[1]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AA = Mot_Commencent_Par_AA.text.split('\n')
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2520);")
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3520);")
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4220);")
Mot_Commencent_Par_AB = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[2]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AB = Mot_Commencent_Par_AB.text.split('\n')
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 6520);")
time.sleep(1)
Page_3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a')
page_3 = Page_3.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1220);")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2520);")
time.sleep(2.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AB2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[1]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AB2 = Mot_Commencent_Par_AB2.text.split('\n')
##################################""" LETTRE AB2 RECUPERER"""##########################
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3220);")
time.sleep(2)
##################################""" ON COMMENCE A RECUPERER AC """##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4520);")
time.sleep(2.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AC = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[2]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AC = Mot_Commencent_Par_AC.text.split('\n')
##################################""" LETTRE AC RECUPERER"""##########################
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 6520);")
time.sleep(1)
##################################""" ON PASS A LA PAGE 4"""##########################
Page_4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a')
page_4 = Page_4.click()
time.sleep(3)
##################################""" ON SE FAIT PASSER POUR UN HUMAIN(ON SCROLL petit à petit)"""##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1720);")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3720);")
##################################""" ON COMMENCE A RECUPERER AC2 """##########################
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4220);")
time.sleep(2.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AC2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[1]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AC2 = Mot_Commencent_Par_AC2.text.split('\n')
##################################""" LETTRE AC2 RECUPERER"""##########################
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 6520);")
time.sleep(1)
##################################""" ON PASS A LA PAGE 5"""##########################
Page_5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a')
page_5 = Page_5.click()
time.sleep(3)
##################################""" ON SE FAIT PASSER POUR UN HUMAIN(ON SCROLL petit à petit)"""##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1220);")
time.sleep(2)
##################################""" ON COMMENCE A RECUPERER AC3 """##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2920);")
time.sleep(1.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AC3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[1]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AC3 = Mot_Commencent_Par_AC3.text.split('\n')
##################################""" LETTRE AC3 RECUPERER"""##########################
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3220);")
time.sleep(2)
##################################""" ON COMMENCE A RECUPERER AD """##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4520);")
time.sleep(2.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AD = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[2]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AD = Mot_Commencent_Par_AD.text.split('\n')
##################################""" LETTRE AD RECUPERER"""##########################
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 6520);")
time.sleep(1)
##################################""" ON PASS A LA PAGE 6"""##########################
Page_6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a')
page_6 = Page_6.click()
time.sleep(3)
##################################""" ON SE FAIT PASSER POUR UN HUMAIN(ON SCROLL petit à petit)"""##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1720);")
time.sleep(2)
##################################""" ON COMMENCE A RECUPERER AE """##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2720);")
time.sleep(1)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AD2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[1]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AD2 = Mot_Commencent_Par_AD2.text.split('\n')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4520);")
time.sleep(2.5)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AE = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[2]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AE = Mot_Commencent_Par_AE.text.split('\n')
##################################""" LETTRE AE RECUPERER"""##########################
time.sleep(1.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4520);")
time.sleep(1)
##################################""" ON PASS A LA PAGE 7"""##########################
Page_7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a')
page_7 = Page_7.click()
time.sleep(3)
##################################""" ON SE FAIT PASSER POUR UN HUMAIN(ON SCROLL petit à petit)"""##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1720);")
time.sleep(2)
##################################""" ON COMMENCE A RECUPERER AE2 """##########################
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2720);")
time.sleep(1)
Mot_Commencent_Par_AE2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul[1]')
Mot_Commencent_Par_AE2 = Mot_Commencent_Par_AE2.text.split('\n')
```

I would like to know how it is possible to make it less long

Comment: i wonder how did you write those code, by some auto generating tools?

Comment: I used selenium with python and I made coll copy on drive.fin_element_by_xpath

Comment: It can definitely be improved with common functions.

Comment: I have a bit of trouble with his :-(

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with squeezing this part:

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 220);")
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1320);")
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2720);")
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4220);")
time.sleep(2.5)
```

Remove it, add `from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains` and leave this:

```
Mot_Commencent_Par_A = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/ul')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Mot_Commencent_Par_A).perform()
```

Do the same with other WebElements. If ActionChains won't work - merge those scrollTo's into one.